# upload error with weird error

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdf

when I'm upload a pdf it give me the code below. it doesn't show what kind of error like the file is too large or the file is not pdf instead it print out the form in the browser.

it's not the matter the file size, I've upload the file under 5 MB, and i already change the file size into 15 MB and set my php.ini more than 10MB and it's still the same. I think there's some problem on script that i missed. if it's error it supposes show error messages from error handler or from php it self rather than the code above.

```
 <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="5242880">

    <fieldset><legend>Fill out the form to add a PDF to the site:</legend>

<div class="form-group has-error"><label for="title" class="control-label">Title</label><input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control"><span class="help-block">Please enter the title!</span></div><div class="form-group has-error"><label for="description" class="control-label">Description</label><span class="help-block">Please enter the description!</span><textarea name="description" id="description" class="form-control"></textarea></div><div class="form-group has-error"><label for="pdf" class="control-label">PDF</label><input type="file" name="pdf" id="pdf"><span class="help-block">No file was uploaded.</span><span class="help-block">PDF only, 5MB Limit</span>
</div>      <input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Add This PDF" id="submit_button" class="btn btn-default" />

    </fieldset>

</form> 

            <!-- END CONTENT -->
            </div><!--/col-9-->

        </div><!--/row-->

      </div><!--/container-->

    </div><!--/wrap-->

    <div id="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <p class="text-muted credit"><span class="pull-left"><a href="site_map.php">Site Map</a> | <a href="policies.php">Policies</a></span> <span class="pull-right">&copy; Knowledge is Power - 2013</span></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
0
```

here's the PHP code:

```
<?php

// This page is used by an administrator to add a PDF to the site.
// This script is created in Chapter 5.

// Require the configuration before any PHP code as the configuration controls error reporting:
require('./includes/config.inc.php');

// If the user isn't logged in as an administrator, redirect them:
redirect_invalid_user('user_admin');

// Require the database connection:
require(MYSQL);

// Include the header file:
$page_title = 'Add a PDF';
include('./includes/header.html');

// For storing errors:
$add_pdf_errors = array();

// Check for a form submission:
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {    

    // Check for a title:
    if (!empty($_POST['title'])) {
        $t = escape_data(strip_tags($_POST['title']), $dbc);
    } else {
        $add_pdf_errors['title'] = 'Please enter the title!';
    }

    // Check for a description:
    if (!empty($_POST['description'])) {
        $d = escape_data(strip_tags($_POST['description']), $dbc);
    } else {
        $add_pdf_errors['description'] = 'Please enter the description!';
    }

    // Check for a PDF:
    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name']) && ($_FILES['pdf']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK)) {

        // Get a reference:
        $file = $_FILES['pdf'];

        // Find the size:
        $size = ROUND($file['size']/1024);

        // Validate the file size (5MB max):
        if ($size > 15120) {
            $add_pdf_errors['pdf'] = 'The uploaded file was too large.';
        } 

        // Validate the file type:
        // Create the resource:
        $fileinfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);

        // Check the file:
        if (finfo_file($fileinfo, $file['tmp_name']) !== 'application/pdf') {
            $add_pdf_errors['pdf'] = 'The uploaded file was not a PDF.';
        } 

        // Close the resource:
        finfo_close($fileinfo);

        // Move the file over, if no problems:
        if (!array_key_exists('pdf', $add_pdf_errors)) {

            // Create a tmp_name for the file:
            $tmp_name = sha1($file['name']) . uniqid('',true);

            // Move the file to its proper folder but add _tmp, just in case:
            $dest =  PDFS_DIR . $tmp_name . '_tmp';

            if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $dest)) {

                // Store the data in the session for later use:
                $_SESSION['pdf']['tmp_name'] = $tmp_name;
                $_SESSION['pdf']['size'] = $size;
                $_SESSION['pdf']['file_name'] = $file['name'];

                // Print a message:
                echo '<div class="alert alert-success"><h3>The file has been uploaded!</h3></div>';

            } else {
                trigger_error('The file could not be moved.');
                unlink ($file['tmp_name']);             
            }

        } // End of array_key_exists() IF.

    } elseif (!isset($_SESSION['pdf'])) { // No current or previous uploaded file.
        switch ($_FILES['pdf']['error']) {
            case 1:
            case 2:
                $add_pdf_errors['pdf'] = 'The uploaded file was too large.';
                break;
            case 3:
                $add_pdf_errors['pdf'] = 'The file was only partially uploaded.';
                break;
            case 6:
            case 7:
            case 8:
                $add_pdf_errors['pdf'] = 'The file could not be uploaded due to a system error.';
                break;
            case 4:
            default: 
                $add_pdf_errors['pdf'] = 'No file was uploaded.';
                break;
        } // End of SWITCH.

    } // End of $_FILES IF-ELSEIF-ELSE.

    if (empty($add_pdf_errors)) { // If everything's OK.

        // Add the PDF to the database:
        $fn = escape_data($_SESSION['pdf']['file_name'], $dbc);
        $tmp_name = escape_data($_SESSION['pdf']['tmp_name'], $dbc);
        $size = (int) $_SESSION['pdf']['size'];
        $q = "INSERT INTO pdfs (title, description, tmp_name, file_name, size) VALUES ('$t', '$d', '$tmp_name', '$fn', $size)";
        $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
        if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) === 1) { // If it ran OK.

            // Rename the temporary file:
            $original =  PDFS_DIR . $tmp_name . '_tmp';
            $dest =  PDFS_DIR . $tmp_name;
            rename($original, $dest);

            // Print a message:
            echo '<div class="alert alert-success"><h3>The PDF has been added!</h3></div>';

            // Clear $_POST:
            $_POST = array();

            // Clear $_FILES:
            $_FILES = array();

            // Clear $file and $_SESSION['pdf']:
            unset($file, $_SESSION['pdf']);

        } else { // If it did not run OK.
            trigger_error('The PDF could not be added due to a system error. We apologize for any inconvenience.');
            unlink ($dest);
        }

    } // End of $errors IF.

} else { // Clear out the session on a GET request:
    unset($_SESSION['pdf']);    
} // End of the submission IF.

// Need the form functions script, which defines create_form_input():
require('includes/form_functions.inc.php');
?><h1>Add a PDF</h1>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="add_pdf.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">

    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="5242880">

    <fieldset><legend>Fill out the form to add a PDF to the site:</legend>

<?php
create_form_input('title', 'text', 'Title', $add_pdf_errors); 
create_form_input('description', 'textarea', 'Description', $add_pdf_errors); 

// Add the file input:
echo '<div class="form-group';

// Add classes, if applicable:
if (array_key_exists('pdf', $add_pdf_errors)) {
    echo ' has-error'; 
} else if (isset($_SESSION['pdf'])) {
    echo ' has-success'; 
}
echo '"><label for="pdf" class="control-label">PDF</label><input type="file" name="pdf" id="pdf">';

// Check for an error:
if (array_key_exists('pdf', $add_pdf_errors)) {

    echo '<span class="help-block">' . $add_pdf_errors['pdf'] . '</span>';

} else { // No error.

    // If the file exists (from a previous form submission but there were other errors),
    // store the file info in a session and note its existence:     
    if (isset($_SESSION['pdf'])) {
        echo '<p class="lead">Currently: "' . $_SESSION['pdf']['file_name'] . '"</p>';
    }

} // end of errors IF-ELSE.
echo '<span class="help-block">PDF only, 5MB Limit</span>
</div>';

?>
        <input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Add This PDF" id="submit_button" class="btn btn-default" />

    </fieldset>

</form> 

<?php // Include the HTML footer:
include('./includes/footer.html');
?>
```

Comment: form enctype  multipart/form-data

Comment: can you explain the detail?